# How do I use Norton's Theorem to find the current in this resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-theory, norton, y-to-delta

I've been trying to solve this question but it seems impossible

[image: Assignment]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. What research you have done. We do not normally answer homework questions on this channel, but we will help you towards a solution.

Comment: Gordon Atsunyo - Welcome :-) As commented, for assignment / test / homework-type questions like this, we need to see your own work *first*. That is currently missing, so your question has been "[closed](/help/closed-questions)". However as explained in that link, it will be put in a queue to consider re-opening it, if you [Edit] your question, add your own analysis & your best solution attempt so far (how are you trying to approach this and why?) and make it clear *exactly* where you are stuck in that analysis. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As usual for homework questions, here are some hints:

Remove the 3ohm resistor between A and B and apply Norton's theorem at the terminals A and B.

To do this you have to calculate the open circuit voltage Voc between A and B (with that resistor removed!) and then the short-circuit current Isc between A and B (turn that 3ohm resistor in a short circuit).

The Norton generator will be Isc, whereas the Norton resistance will be Voc/Isc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is advice and the first hint to get you started:

[image]

I'm saying draw it "correctly" because it just isn't proper engineering showing connections like these: -

[image]

**Reason:** those badly-drawn connections yield a solution that is basically trivial.

**Detail is all-important in engineering.**

So, moving on, you then calculate the resistance between C and D ignoring the 10 volt power supply and its series resistor. This can use Norton's Theorem but it can also use Thevenin's theorem. Can you take it from here?

Once you have that resistance, you can then calculate what the voltage between C and D is when the 10 volt supply is reintroduced.

Answer (score -4):

[image: Isc]

[image: RN]

Maybe you were confused in finding out Req/RN/Rth....

Comment: This does not answer the question. This just solves the homework without explaining what was asked; i.e. how to use Norton to solve it. Please do not give solutions to homework questions when the original post shows no effort to solve it.